# How to store image from camera to server using ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Want to retrieve image from camera and display it on page. On click of save button want to store same image over the server.

Getting below error on save

```
FileTransferError:
body: null
code: 1
exception: null
http_status: null
source: "data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUA..."
target: "https://www.myweb.com/api/product/storesimage/images"
```

here my code for taking picture

```
takePhoto(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        this.Photo = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {

    });
  }
```

save image code

```
  saveImage() {

    const uploadOpts: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey: "file",
        fileName: 'name.jpg',
        chunkedMode: false,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data"
    }

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    fileTransfer.upload(this.Photo, 'https://www.myweb.com/api/product/storesimage/images', uploadOpts)
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use ionic file-transfer check the ionic-documentation for details. As you know.
See [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file-transfer/)

A problem is also that you have to provide the tansfer service. Add a provider in app.module or in the module of your component:

import { Transfer } from "../providers/file-transfer";
in your app.module. And,

providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }, Storage, Transfer]

It there is no provider you get a null-pointer exception ! The provider entry is needed to get a own instance of the service.
I hope this helps.